# Simple vocabulary trainer based on flashcards

Tags: java, console

**Motivation**

When I was young, I had to learn english in school and I was really bad. My father told me to write words on little cards, with a word on the one side and its foreign counterpart on the backside. These flashcards were in a box with 5 categories: 5 is very bad and 1 is very well trained. When i guessed a word correctly, it got moved one category up, and if not it got moved down (for example from 4 to 5).

I suddenly got interested in learning english and make notes in a csv about unknown words. I then searched for a simple vocabulary trainer that deals with csv and tried also anki but there was no program that I like, so I tried to make a simple cli tool for that.

What do you think about my code? And especially: Is my way of file handling state of art? I have to admit that I've done a lot without security features to keep that program small and simple.

**About a code**

I maybe later want to write a GUI program with Swing so I tried to write code that can later easily be adapted for the event handlers etc. The structure is a simple one: Objects of TrainingSession read a csv file and allows a user to be trained in a given category. When a session is over, the file gets properly updated. It maintaines a list of objects of Flashcard for that purpose. This class represents a flashcard and some additional information like example sentences, if given.

**Latest Version (not to be covered here)**

https://login.yoursecurecloud.de/d/2b731dee455b49d19913/

**Main.java**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        System.out.print("Category: ");
        int input = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        TrainingSession session = new TrainingSession(input);
        session.train();
    }
}
```

**TrainingSession.java**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class TrainingSession {
    private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static Random random = new Random();
    private List<Flashcard> flashcards;
    private List<Flashcard> otherFlashcards;
    private String headlines;
    
    public TrainingSession(int categoryToTrain) {
        List<String> lines = null;
        try {
            lines = Files.readAllLines(new File("./flashcards.csv").toPath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        // first line are headlines
        headlines = lines.get(0);
        lines.remove(0);
        
        flashcards = new ArrayList<>();
        otherFlashcards = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String line : lines) {
            String[] parts = line.split(";");
            
            int categoryOfLine = Integer.parseInt(parts[4]);
            parts[1] = parts[1].replace(", ", ",");
            List<String> words = List.of(parts[1].split(","));
            
            if (categoryOfLine == categoryToTrain)
                flashcards.add(new Flashcard(parts[0], words, parts[2], parts[3], Integer.parseInt(parts[4])));
            else
                otherFlashcards.add(new Flashcard(parts[0], words, parts[2], parts[3], Integer.parseInt(parts[4])));
        }
    }
    
    public void train() {
        while (flashcards.size() > 0) {
            Flashcard current = flashcards.get(random.nextInt(flashcards.size()));
            System.out.println(current.getWord() + " (" + current.getWordClass() + ")");
            if (!current.getExampleSentence().isEmpty())
                System.out.println("Example Sentence: " + current.getExampleSentence());
            System.out.print("Input: ");
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            if (current.guess(input)) {
                System.out.println("Correct!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong!");
            }
            flashcards.remove(current);
            otherFlashcards.add(current);
            System.out.println("Correct words: " + current.getWordsToLearn() + "\n");
        }
        
        // saveProgress
        StringBuilder fileContent = new StringBuilder();
        fileContent.append(headlines + "\n");
        for (Flashcard flashcard : otherFlashcards) {
            fileContent.append(flashcard.toCsvString() + "\n");
        }
        
        try {
            Files.write(Paths.get("./flashcards.csv"), fileContent.toString().getBytes());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Flashcard.java**

```
import java.util.List;

public class Flashcard {
    private String word;
    private List<String> wordsToLearn;
    private String wordClass; 
    private String exampleSentence;
    private int category; // from 1 to 5. 1 = well trained, 5 = newly added for learning
    
    public Flashcard(String word, List<String> wordsToLearn, String wordClass, String exampleSentence, int category) {
        this.word = word;
        this.wordsToLearn = wordsToLearn;
        this.wordClass = wordClass;
        this.exampleSentence = exampleSentence;
        this.category = category;
    }
    
    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public String getWordsToLearn() {
        return String.join(", ", wordsToLearn);
    }

    public String getWordClass() {
        return wordClass;
    }

    public String getExampleSentence() {
        return exampleSentence;
    }

    public int getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public boolean guess(String guess) {
        boolean right = StaticFunctions.equalsOneOf(guess, wordsToLearn, true);
        
        if (right && category > 1) {
            category--;
        } else {
            if (category < 5) {
                category++;
            }
        }
        
        return right;
    }
    
    public String toCsvString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(word + ";");
        sb.append(getWordsToLearn() + ";");
        sb.append(wordClass + ";");
        sb.append(exampleSentence + ";");
        sb.append(category);
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**StaticFunctions.java**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public abstract class StaticFunctions {
    public static boolean equalsOneOf(String str, List<String> strList, boolean ignoreCase) {
        for (String strFromList : strList) {
            if (strFromList.equals(str)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

**flashcards.csv**

```
Wort;Lernwort;Wortart;Beispielsatz;Kategorie
run;laufen, rennen;Verb;They run into the forrest.;3
home;Haus;Substantiv;I go home.;4
```

Comment: There's a typo in the data file - should be "forest", not "forrest".  Yes, English spelling is an inconsistent nightmare!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall looks and works well. Nice job!

Some minor things that could be improved...

- Flashcard.java

  - Looks like everything except for the category field could be declared as `final`
  - Avoid string concatenation in a StringBuilder
- Main.java

  - The scanner can be declared as `final`
- StaticFunctions.java

  - Looks like the `ArrayList` class can be removed from the imports
  - Also looks like parameter `ignoreCase` isn't used
- TrainingSession.java

  - Looks like the fields could be made `final`
  - Avoid string concatenation in a StringBuilder

Answer (score 1):

You should reuse a single instance of `Scanner` rather than recreating it.

Don't `parseInt(scanner.nextLine())`; instead use `nextInt`.

Avoid random-indexing and iteratively mutating your flashcards collection. Instead, just `shuffle` it once on construction and then iterate through that.

You should not `printStackTrace` and then continue on with the training session constructor; that exception should be fatal.

Consider carving out a CSV parser class from your training session constructor. This logic is not robust enough because it doesn't pay attention to the CSV headers; in theory the CSV columns should survive permutation and still load correctly.

Rather than successive string append like `println(current.getWord() + " (" + current.getWordClass() + ")");`, prefer `printf` or `formatted` style.

You should write out replacement lines (one on every guess) to a new, temporary CSV file. Then on close, delete the old file and rename the new one.

`Flashcard` should be a `record`, and its boilerplate accessors removed. Avoid mutating it. When you promote or demote the category, it's cheap enough to just produce a new instance and this guarantee of immutability offers design benefits.

All of `StaticFunctions` should be deleted. There is a simple-enough way to get a boolean from a match stream and keep the case-insensitive behaviour.

### Suggested

**Main.java**

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().train();
    }

    public void train() {
        System.out.print("Category: ");
        int category = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();

        try (TrainingSession session = new TrainingSession(scanner, category)) {
            session.train();
        }
    }
}
```

**TrainingSession.java**

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class TrainingSession implements AutoCloseable {
    private final Scanner scanner;
    private final List<Flashcard> promptFlashcards;
    private final CsvFile file;

    public TrainingSession(Scanner scanner, int categoryToTrain) {
        this.scanner = scanner;

        List<Flashcard> flashcards;

        try {
            file = new CsvFile("flashcards.csv");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        flashcards = file.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        flashcards.stream()
            .filter(c -> c.category() != categoryToTrain)
            .forEach(file::write);

        promptFlashcards = flashcards.stream()
            .filter(c -> c.category() == categoryToTrain)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        Collections.shuffle(promptFlashcards);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        try {
            file.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public void train() {
        for (Flashcard card: promptFlashcards) {
            System.out.print(card.getPrompt());

            System.out.print("German word: ");
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            Flashcard updated;
            if (card.guess(input)) {
                System.out.println("Correct!");
                updated = card.withPromotedCategory();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong!");
                updated = card.withDemotedCategory();
            }
            file.write(updated);

            System.out.printf("Correct words: %s%n%n", card.formatWordsToLearn());
        }
    }
}
```

**CsvFile.java**

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class CsvFile implements AutoCloseable {
    private final File fileIn, fileTemp;
    private final Scanner scanner;
    private final PrintStream writer;
    private final int wordIdx, learnIdx, classIdx, exampleIdx, categoryIdx;

    public CsvFile(String filename) throws IOException {
        fileIn = new File(filename);
        fileTemp = File.createTempFile(filename, "updated");
        scanner = new Scanner(fileIn);
        writer = new PrintStream(fileTemp);

        // Wort;Lernwort;Wortart;Beispielsatz;Kategorie
        // Word;Learning word;Part of speech;Example sentence;Category
        String headerLine = scanner.nextLine();
        writer.println(headerLine);
        List<String> header = List.of(headerLine.split(";"));
        wordIdx = header.indexOf("Wort");
        learnIdx = header.indexOf("Lernwort");
        classIdx = header.indexOf("Wortart");
        exampleIdx = header.indexOf("Beispielsatz");
        categoryIdx = header.indexOf("Kategorie");
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        writer.close();
        scanner.close();
        Files.delete(fileIn.toPath());
        Files.move(fileTemp.toPath(), fileIn.toPath());
    }

    public Stream<Flashcard> stream() {
        return Stream.generate(this::read)
            .takeWhile(Objects::nonNull);
    }

    Flashcard read() {
        if (!scanner.hasNextLine())
            return null;
        String[] parts = scanner.nextLine().split(";");

        return new Flashcard(
            parts[wordIdx],
            List.of(parts[learnIdx].split(", *")),
            parts[classIdx],
            parts[exampleIdx],
            Integer.parseInt(parts[categoryIdx])
        );
    }

    void write(Flashcard card) {
        String[] parts = new String[5];
        parts[wordIdx] = card.word();
        parts[learnIdx] = card.formatWordsToLearn();
        parts[classIdx] = card.wordClass();
        parts[exampleIdx] = card.exampleSentence();
        parts[categoryIdx] = Integer.toString(card.category());
        writer.println(String.join(";", parts));
    }
}
```

**Flashcard.java**

```java
import java.util.List;

public record Flashcard(
    String word,
    List<String> wordsToLearn,
    String wordClass,
    String exampleSentence,
    int category  // from 1 to 5. 1 = well trained, 5 = newly added for learning
) {
    public String getPrompt() {
        String out = "%s (%s)%n".formatted(word, wordClass);
        if (exampleSentence.isBlank())
            return out;
        return out + "Example Sentence: %s%n".formatted(exampleSentence);
    }

    public String formatWordsToLearn() {
        return String.join(", ", wordsToLearn);
    }

    public boolean guess(String guess) {
        return wordsToLearn.stream()
            .anyMatch(word -> word.equalsIgnoreCase(guess));
    }

    public Flashcard withPromotedCategory() {
        return new Flashcard(
            word, wordsToLearn, wordClass, exampleSentence,
            Integer.max(1, category - 1)
        );
    }

    public Flashcard withDemotedCategory() {
        return new Flashcard(
            word, wordsToLearn, wordClass, exampleSentence,
            Integer.min(5, category + 1)
        );
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Category: 3
run (Verb)
Example Sentence: They run into the forest.
German word: laufen
Correct!
Correct words: laufen, rennen
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer! I rewrite the file because when a word is solved right, it moves a category up (f. e. from 4 to 3). When it is wrong, it moves down (from 3 to 4).

Comment: @DexterThorn I think I understand now, so I've updated the code accordingly.

Comment: Ah thanks. I find it interesting that you create a new Object for increasing or decreasing the category. Wouldnt it save computing time when you just increment or decrement an integer?

Comment: It might (very slightly), or it might not at all; that would need to be profiled. In this trade-off, the more important factor is good structure, and premature optimization will get in the way. More generally, this is a topic during the performance analysis of functional programming, but in this specific case the value of immutability outweighs any imperceptible performance benefit.

Comment: For some good reading, see [Why is Java making so many things immutable?](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/java-immutable-objects-strings-date-time-records).

Comment: Aah okay I will read that